# Unable to upgrade package to experimental on debian

Tags: debian

I have been trying to install gnome 40 on my debian 11 desktop, but can't figure it out.
I have added these to my /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main non-free contrib

deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main non-free contrib

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main non-free contrib

## Experimental for Gnome 40 ##
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian experimental main
```

then I ran apt **update**; apt **upgrade**; **dist-upgrade**; and rebooted.

And then, whenever I try to run this command:

```
sudo apt -t experimental install gnome-shell gnome-backgrounds gnome-applets gnome-control-center mutter gjs
```

I get this output:

```
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances... Fait
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait      
gjs est déjà la version la plus récente (1.66.2-1).
gjs passé en « installé manuellement ».
gnome-applets est déjà la version la plus récente (3.38.0-1).
gnome-backgrounds est déjà la version la plus récente (3.38.0-1).
gnome-control-center est déjà la version la plus récente (1:3.38.4-1).
gnome-shell est déjà la version la plus récente (3.38.6-1~deb11u1).
mutter est déjà la version la plus récente (3.38.6-2~deb11u1).
mutter passé en « installé manuellement ».
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
```

which says that every one of these packages is already up to date with version 3.38 so nothing was updated nor installed.

First post on stackexchange, thank you for your help

Comment: Well I've tried installing GNOME 41 from this tutorial : https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-gnome-41-desktop-unstable-on-debian-11-bullseye/#Update_Operating_System
but it still says that gnome 3.38 is the latest version and I can't get higher

Comment: Your totorial is misleading. It describes how to install unstable packages and/or to upgrade to unstable then concludes "you have learned about Debian’s experimental repository" which isn't what was done, just because of a single changelog in a screenshot as "proof". The only word "experimental" appears in this single sentence and nowhere else (beside the screenshot).

Comment: see also: [Don't make a FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian)

Answer (score 0):

Why it doesn't work? because the list of packages isn't available on debian experimental. E,g: [`gnome-applets`](https://packages.debian.org/experimental/gnome-applets) is available only for power pc as a source package. `gnome-shell` isn't available...

The safe way to get gnome 40 is to upgrade to debian  bookworm.

Answer (score 0):

As the Debian wiki for [Experimental](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianExperimental) says, Experimental repo is an extension of Unstable. It is not possible to use the Experimental repository with the Stable or Testing repository because packages in Experimental repository have dependencies on packages which are only available in Unstable. If you want the latest software, Stable is not for you and you may want to point your sources file to the Unstable repository. Also, you may want to read the [guidelines](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian) on how to use Debian without breaking it.